# Help creating quite complex Tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I would like to creat the attached figure in Tikz.

As i am quite new to tikz i do not know what to use and how to start.[image]

As it has some intricate lines and arrows.
Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Can you at least draw triangles and ellipses by the help of the manual about `shapes.geometric` library? Starting an example from scratch really is not fun.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Here is another one, `diag.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(400);
pair O=(0,0);
// triangle
pair[] ptriangle={(-186,-92),(186,-92),(0,185),};

pen penT=darkblue+1bp;
pen penEl=orange+1bp+linetype(new real[] {5,3,2,3});
// draw triangle
draw(ptriangle[0]--ptriangle[1]--ptriangle[2]--cycle,penT);

// a fucntion to draw an ellipse defined by the center and x- and y-scale factors
void ellipse(pair center,real xs,real ys,pen p=currentpen){
  draw(shift(center)*scale(xs,ys)*unitcircle,p);
};

ellipse(ptriangle[2],255,120,penEl);
ellipse(ptriangle[0],180,140,penEl);
ellipse(ptriangle[1],180,140,penEl);

guide[] thickArr={
  (-147,161)..(-224,68)..(-210,-38),
  (206,159)..(280,67)..(264,-34),
  (-105,-157)..(-4,-208)..(95,-168),
};

pen squarecap=linecap(0);
pen roundcap=linecap(1);
pen extendcap=linecap(2);

pen dashed=squarecap+linetype(new real[] {1.5,1.5}); // set up dashed pattern

pen penThickArr=dashed+2bp;
pen penThinArr=red+extendcap;

for(int i=0;i<thickArr.length;++i){
  draw(thickArr[i], penThickArr,Arrows(size=5));
}

guide[] thinArr={
  (-68,-35)--(67,-35),
  (69,-12)--(10,99),
  (-8,101)--(-67,-13),
};

for(int i=0;i<thickArr.length;++i){
  draw(thinArr[i], penThinArr,Arrows);
}

string[] planeLabel={"MNE","Subsidiary 1","HQ","Subsidiary 2"};

pair[] planeLabelPos={(0,40),(143,-58),(2,106),(-149,-57)};
pair[] planeLabelAlign={
  O,W,N,E
};

defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

for(int i=0;i<planeLabel.length;++i){
  label(planeLabel[i],planeLabelPos[i],planeLabelAlign[i]);
}

pair[] listLabelPos={(0,235),(187,-149),(-210,-142)};

string[] listLabel={
  minipage("\textit{Home Country Context}"
  +"\begin{itemize}"
  +"\item Resources" 
  +"\item Institutions" 
  +"\end{itemize}"
  ,width=120pt),
  minipage("\textit{Host Context 1}"
  +"\begin{itemize}"
  +"\item Resources" 
  +"\item Institutions" 
  +"\end{itemize}"
  ,width=100pt),
  minipage("\textit{Host Context 2}"
  +"\begin{itemize}"
  +"\item Resources" 
  +"\item Institutions" 
  +"\end{itemize}"
  ,width=100pt),
};

pair[] listLabelAlign={O,O,O};

for(int i=0;i<listLabel.length;++i){
  label(listLabel[i],listLabelPos[i],listLabelAlign[i]);
}
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf diag.tex`.

Comment: It really looks the part. I'm not sure I'd know how to work Latexmk...

Comment: @wierts: It is always possible to copy the `Asymptote` code found between `\begin{asy}` and `\end{asy}` into a file, for example, `d.asy` and process it with a command `asy -f pdf d.asy` to get a standalone figure `d.pdf`, which can be used as any other `pdf` picture.

Answer (score 7):

A possibility, still admitting improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shapes.geometric,fit}

\newcommand\NText[1]{%
\begin{varwidth}[t]{10cm}
\textit{#1}\\[-2ex]
\begin{itemize}[nolistsep]
\item Resources
\item Institutions
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}%
}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (-2.25,0) (sub2) {Subsidiary 2};
\node at (2.25,0) (sub1) {Subsidiary 1};
\node at ([yshift=-2cm] $ (-2.25,0) + (60:5cm) $ ) (hc) {HQ};
\node at (barycentric cs:sub1=0.5,sub2=0.5,hc=0.7) {MNE};

\node[align=left,below left= 20pt and -1cm of sub2]
  (con2) {\NText{Host Context 2}};
\node[draw,dashdotted,ellipse,fit=(sub2)(con2)] (fit2) {};

\node[align=left,below right= 20pt and -1cm of sub1]
  (con1) {\NText{Host Context 1}};
\node[draw,dashdotted,ellipse,fit=(sub1)(con1)] (fit1) {};

\node[align=left,above= 20pt of hc]
  (con3) {\NText{Home Country Context}};
\node[draw,dashdotted,ellipse,fit=(hc)(con3)] (fit3) {};

\draw 
  ([yshift=0.5cm]hc.north) -- 
  ([xshift=0.8cm,yshift=-0.5cm]sub1.east) -- 
  ([xshift=-0.8cm,yshift=-0.5cm]sub2.west) -- 
  ([yshift=0.5cm]hc.north);

\coordinate (aux1) at ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=0.25cm]sub1.north);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.25cm]sub2.north);
\draw[<->,line width=1pt] (hc) -- (aux1);
\draw[<->,line width=1pt] (hc) -- (aux2);
\draw[<->,line width=1pt] ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-5pt]aux1.west) -- ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-5pt]aux2.east);

\draw[<->,dashed,line width=3pt] 
  ([yshift=-20pt]fit1.north east) 
  to[bend right] 
  ([xshift=-20pt]fit3.east);
\draw[<->,dashed,line width=3pt] 
  ([yshift=-20pt]fit2.north west) 
  to[bend left] 
  ([xshift=20pt]fit3.west);
\draw[<->,dashed,line width=3pt] 
  ([xshift=-25pt]fit2.south east) 
  to[bend right] 
  ([xshift=25pt]fit1.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]